# Is there a place to test Stack Overflow features?

Tags: support

What if I want to test some feature like 'flag' question, retag, delete, etc..

Is there a sandbox where people could do those things without affecting live website?

What about editing?

Comment: If you want to test editing stuff, use the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) as the answers below already states

Comment: I wanted to test what would be displayed in "edited" block if there is more than one edit. Now I know. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flagging should not be "tested". It's for alerting the moderators to posts with serious problems. They get enough valid flags every day, adding "testing" ones will only distract them.

You need 500 reputation to be able to retag someone else's question without needing to suggest an edit. Other things you wish to test may require reputation you don't have. You won't be able to test these.

You can always delete your own question (assuming it has no answers and no up-votes) - but post a one on a meta if you are testing.

You can always delete your own answer regardless of the number of up- or down-votes it has. You even get badges for it: `Disciplined` and `Peer Pressure`, though this should really be reserved for content that is totally wrong.

Comment: "You can always delete your own question"... to be exact, you can do so only if the question has no answers, only mods can delete questions with answers.

Comment: @mzabsky - true.

Comment: Do I need 500 reputation to retag my own question? It looks like I do, but why?

Comment: @Dmitri - no. As you can edit your own question you can change the tags.

Comment: Can I delete my own answer?

Comment: @Dmitri - you can always delete your own answer no matter how many votes it has.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that here on meta.  There's a [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) to test out the editing features.

You'll want to use the site-specific meta sites to test out features not available here (mathematical formula formatting, spoiler formatting, etc.).

Comment: Note that there's a lot of resistance from the devs to add mathematical formula formatting to meta sites; it's a huge piece of javascript to be hosting and distributing and it doesn't get used a lot.  We have it on Electrical Engineering Meta, there's a sandbox [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/434/857) that anyone's welcome to use.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a sandbox where people could do those things without affecting live website?

No.  The only sandbox that exists is the [markdown sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

If you wish to verify that the flag and other voting features work, look around for questions and comments that require such action - they aren't difficult to find - and perform the correct action on the item in question.  If you still have difficulty finding something with which to exercise your abilities, ask for suggestions on chat - there is always some partially closed question that just needs a few more close votes, for instance.